# Understanding a piece of code in CHIP8 emulator

Tags: c++, emulation, bit-shift, opcode

I am writing a CHIP8 emulator. I wrote everything so far, except for the opcode `DXYN`, I looked for some explaination for it, and I found a question in SO, with a code as answer for it. While reading the code, I got stuck on this piece of code which in C says `if((data & (0x80 >> x)) != 0)` what does the `(data & (0x80 >> x))` do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we split it up, we have

```
0x80 >> x
```

which shifts the value `128` (`0x80`) right by `x` bits.

The next part uses the previous result as a mask for `data`, to see if the specific bit it set in `data`.

Then the whole is checked against zero to see if the bit is set or not.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` statement checks if bit #x is set in a byte, counting 0 as the highest bit.

```
Bit#  01234567
      01001010   (0x4A has bit 1, 4 and 6 set)

(data & (0x80 >> x)) returns 0x40 for x=1
                             0x08 for x=4
                             0x02 for x=6
                             0x00 for all other values.
```

`if((data & (0x80 >> x)) != 0)` is in other words true for x=1, x=4 and x=6